# Mocking GeocoderLaravel

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel, laravel-5.1, geocode

I'm using [GeocoderLaravel](https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel) to handle looking up locations via the Google Maps API in a Laravel app. I want to be able to mock the facade so that in tests it doesn't actually query the Google Maps API, so I'm injecting it into the controller, but doing so breaks the controller. Here's the relevant parts of the controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Location;
use Geocoder;

class LocationController extends Controller
{
    protected $geocoder;

    public function __construct(Geocoder $geocoder)
    { 
        $this->geocoder = $geocoder;
    } 

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    { 
        // Get location
        $location = $request->input('location');

        try { 
            // Look up location
            $result = $this->geocoder->geocode($location);

            // Return response
            return response()->json($result->toArray(), 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) { 
            $data = [ 
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ];
            return response()->json($data, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I run the tests or try to make a request to this method:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Toin0u\Geocoder\Facade\Geocoder::geocode()
```

Using PsySh to insert a breakpoint just before that's called, it does indeed look like the `geocode()` method is defined, but I'm not sure why. Can anyone explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Not sure if you got notified about my updated answer, but I've created a pull request to make this package DI friendly. Hopefully you'll be able to inject here soon!

Comment: @jszobody Thanks for that. I've got the other approach working anyway, so that resolves the issue, but it seems like a good idea to add it to the repository since it appears to be a trivial change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inject the facade like that. The [facade](https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel/blob/master/src%2FFacade%2FGeocoder.php) doesn't have a `geocode` method.

Facades are special in that they just provide access to the Laravel IoC, and don't behave like normal classes. They are orthogonal to dependency injection.

You could inject the real `Geocoder\Geocoder` class IF the Service Provider created an alias, but it [doesn't appear](https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel/blob/master/src/GeocoderServiceProvider.php) to be setup that way.

I think you are stuck using the facade as you normally, like `Geocoder::geocode(...)`.

However... checkout how Laravel can mock a facade during testing:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#mocking-facades

That will allow you to test your controller, mock the facade call, so that it doesn't hit Google for real.

### Update:

I've created a pull request to make this DI friendly:

https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel/pull/41

If that request is merged in, you will be able to inject `\Geocoder\Geocoder` in your controller method, which I very much prefer myself!